# Reactive Extensions: Is it possible to subscribe on Sum of the result of Buffer operation?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to get notifications on the result of Aggregate functions (i.e. Sum), which operates on the partial sequence of the infinite sequence (topmost, data source sequence never completes).
The problem can be seen here:

```
var seq = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20)).Buffer(10);
seq.Sum(l => l.Sum())
            .Subscribe(n =>
                s_log.DebugFormat("Got {0}", n));
```

Lambda l.Sum() is called as expected (partial sums are calculated), but "Got ..." line is never printed, because subscriber is never called. I suspected it is related somehow to "never ending" character of the original sequence.
The finite sequence:

```
 Observable.Range(1,100).Buffer(10);
```

works as expected.
So question is simple: how to "mark" partial fragments of the infinite sequence to be "complete", so aggregate functions would work on them separately (and will push their results to subscribers) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.scan%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is your friend:

```
seq.Scan(0L, (l1, l2) => l1 + l2.Sum())
   .Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", n));
```

Comment: You are right, but why ? I plan to integrate RX extensions with our app server, so customers of the app server could use RX extensions mixed with our code. I can't explain them why .Scan will lead to notification code to be called, and .Sum won't (their code will be called through our thread scheduler according to apartment rules, and if they don't get a notification they will blame us, at least initially). In the past I integrated Task/await+async seamlessly, it didn't got ever one usability-related question for 3 years, the stuff was so intuitive ... RX looks like a big promise

Comment: I can't really answer why. I can say that `Min`, `Max`, `Sum`, `Average`, `Count`, and `Aggregate` all work the same way. My best guess is that they're meant to by similar to LINQ to Objects, where `.Sum` (and friends) only complete once the enumerable finishes.

Comment: The problem is that Aggregate and Scan in theory do the same. RX in general aims to make handling of data streams easier,  right? So I'd expect behavior of each method when applied to infinite stream to be clearly indicated (like thread safety properties are stated for each class and method). There are many subtle different things, like Aggregate and Scan, Buffer and Window,  etc - and no easy discoverable source of information what are differences and when should you use which variant. Anyway,  thanks for your help.

Comment: `Aggregate` and `Scan` in theory are similar, but not the same. When you call Sum on an `IEnumerable<int>` instance do you get one scalar result or do you get series of values in an IEnumerable<int>? The answer is that you only get a single scalar value. IObservable.Sum() also only returns a single value, but it has to be in the future/async, thus the return type is `IObservable<int>`. It could have been `Task<int>` but then you are mixing concurrency paradigms. `Scan` in contrast will yield all of the intermediate values as they are calculated; perfect for running totals.